# Problems with 'while' loop and 'for' loop when reading through file

Tags: python, python-idle

I wasted plenty of hours trying to figure out the problem but no luck. Tried asking the TA at my school, but he was useless. I am a beginner and I know there are a lot of mistakes in it, so it would be great if I can get some detail explanation as well. Anyways, basically what I am trying to do with the following function is:

- Use while loop to check and see if random_string is in TEXT, if not
  return NoneType
- if yes, then use a for loop to read lines from that  TEXT and put it
  in list, l1.
- then, write an if statement to see if random_string is in l1.
- if it is, then do some calculations.
- else read the next line
- Finally, return the calculations as a whole.

---

```
TEXT = open('randomfile.txt')

def random (TEXT, random_string):
    while random_string in TEXT:
        for lines in TEXT:
            l1=TEXT.readline().rsplit()
            if random_string in l1:
                '''
                    do some calculations
                '''
            else:
                TEXT.readline() #read next line???
        return #calculations
    return None
```

Comment: So... you've told us what you're trying to do. What has failed? What has worked? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I removed the `homework` tag as it's obsolete and the homework part is clear from the formulation of the question.

Comment: Dear user "test" if you want to dele your question, delete it, but don't make it a silly text without any sense...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe?:

```
def my_func(ccy):
    with open('randomfile.txt', 'r') as f:
        l1 = [float(line.split()[-1]) for line in f.readlines() if ccy in line]
        if l1:
            return sum(l1) / len(l1)
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: I guess that while random_string in lines: line already means that you are looking through all lines within file so that's why i decided to save lines into variable and use it. In case you don't need while loop -then it would not be a problem to read line by line or i am wrong

Comment: Simply provide more details - so we will able to answer - what kind of file you have, what data is in each line and etc

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the calculation is a function of the line, then:

```
def my_func(fileobj,random_string,calculation_func):
    return [calculation_func(line) for line in fileobj if random_string in line] or None
```

otherwise, you could do this:

```
def my_func(fileobj,random_string):
    calculated = []
    for line in fileobj:
        if random_string in line:
            #do calculations, append to calculated
    return calculated or None
```

I omitted the while loop because it would needlessly increase the complexity of the function.  `fileobj` assumes a file-like object, such as a buffer or like one returned by `open`.

**Edit** With while loop:

```
def my_func(fileobj,random_string):
    calculated = []
    try:
        while True: #remnant from competitive programming - makes it faster
            line = fileobj.readline()
            if random_string in line:
                #do calculations, append to calculated
    except EOFError:  #catches the error thrown when calling readline after file is empty.
        return calculated or None
```

**Edit 2**
Taking into account the OP's new information

```
def my_func(fileobj,random_string):
    total = 0
    number = 0
    try:
        while True:
            line = fileobj.readline()
            if random_string in line:
                total += float(line.split()[1])
                number += 1
    if total == number == 0:
        return 0 #or whatever default value if random_string isn't in the file
    return total/number
```

Shorter version:

```
def my_func(fileobj,random_string):
    results = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in fileobj if random_string in line]
    return sum(results)/len(results)
```

Comment: If you go into IDLE, and type `[] or None`, you will get `None`.  So if at the end of the either function, if the list is empty, then it will default to `None`.

Comment: However, if you have one of the two evaluate to `true`, then it will give you the "`true`" value

Answer (score 0):

If I can clarify your requirements:

- Use while loop to check and see if `random_string` is in a file, if not return `None`.
- Collect lines that have `random_string` in a list.
- Do some calculations on the lines collected and return the result of the calculations.

Then the following should get you started:

```
calculation_lines = []
random_string = 'needle'

with open('somefile.txt') as the_file:
   for line in the_file:
       if random_string in line:
           calculation_lines.append(line)

if not calculation_lines:
   return None # no lines matched

for i in calculation_lines:
    # do some calculations
    result_of_calculations = 42

return result_of_calculations
```